Gremlin query, get all the nodes 2 - 4 steps from the selected nodes
I would like to retrieve all the nodes that are 2 to 4 steps away from a selected node.
My thought was that I could separate the query into two repeat().times(2) step so that I can call them later:
Since my graph is very connected, I try to query by taking the shortest path
g.V().has('name', 'a').store('x')
.emit().repeat(outE().inV().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).times(2).as('exclude')
.emit().repeat(outE().inV().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).times(2).as('keep')
.select('keep')
.values('name')
.dedup()

This does not return the correct result.
In fact, if I change this query to
g.V().has('name', 'a').store('x')
.emit().repeat(outE().inV().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).times(2).as('exclude')
.emit().repeat(outE().inV().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).times(2).as('keep')
.select('exclude')
.values('name')
.dedup()

I am only getting the source node back ('a')
what is the correct way to do this? I am using amazon neptune with jupyter graph notebook

Doing the repeat twice within a union maybe the "brute force" way of doing this.  There's likely a better way by traversing through the graph once and then pulling out only the parts that you need:
g.withSack(0).V().has('name','a').
    repeat(
        sack(sum).by(constant(1)).
        out().simplePath()
    ).emit().times(4).
group().
    by(sack()).
unfold().
    where(
        select(keys).is(within([2,4]))
    ).
select(values).unfold().
values('name')

This uses sack() as a way to track depth as you traverse through the graph.  You can then group-by the depth and only return the items at specific depths.
https://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#sackintro

Thank you for your answer Taylor. This is working as expected.
